# How to make index.php?do=johngroup using.htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, url-rewrite-module

Please help me, i can't make rewrite url using .htaccess.
I want to rewrite/redirect all php file to one index.php
Example:

```
index.php?do=johngroup
index.php?do=addmem
index.php?do=autoshare
index.php?do=spamwall
```

Or,

```
http://example.com/index.php?do=johngroup
http://example.com/index.php?do=addmem
http://example.com/index.php?do=autoshare
http://example.com/index.php?do=spamwall
```

One index.php?do= to all my created php file name.

I am trying below code but not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-.]*).php?do=(.*)
RewriteRule .* /%1.php?do=%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me, Sir.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Thanks for comment sir.

Comment: I want to rewrite or redirect all php file to one index.php

Comment: Example: `index.php?do=johngroup`
`index.php?do=addmem`
`index.php?do=autoshare`
`index.php?do=spamwall`

Comment: Hello sir, help me please